# Inserting a row (or column) into a 2D CPP array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

What is the most efficient data structure to use for 2D array in c++ which supports inserting/deleting a row (or column) efficiently?
I know using a `vector<vector<float> >` for a 2D array and `vector::insert()` allows me to do this for rows. Is there a more efficient way? I there a clean way to do this using a `float**` 2D array?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/511/stdvector/17463/matrices-using-vectors#t=20161020145341848837 should help

Comment: The link mentions "A vector of vectors is a convenient way to represent a matrix but it's not the most efficient:"

Comment: a vector of vector is what you have and If I understand correctly you want to know a efficent way to insert elements to what you already have.

Comment: I want to know if there is a better way to represent my 2D array, so that the insert/delete operation is fast.

Comment: "row or column" or "row and column"? I mean, do you need to insert/delete rows and columns in one matrix?

Comment: rows and columns.. but only one of them at 1 time. Example run: insert row -> compute stuff, insert column -> compute stuff, delete column ->compute stuff...